# SOAP request with certain tags without namespace

Tags: soap, namespaces, xml-namespaces

Would be the following SOAP request valid according to the standard?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:ServiceReq xmlns:ns2="http://www.tibco.com/service" xmlns:ns1="http://www.tibco.com/framework">
            <ns1:HeaderIn>
                <ns1:countryISO>FR</ns1:countryISO>
                <ns1:callerDateTime>2021-11-26T15:50:08.742Z</ns1:callerDateTime>
            </ns1:HeaderIn>
            <ns2:request>
                <entete>
                    <profile>Default</profile>
                </entete>
                <input>
                    <type>W</type>
                    <codeRegion>X</codeRegion>
                </input>
            </ns2:request>
        </ns2:ServiceReq>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am not sure because certain tags don't have a namespace

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple levels of valid here:

1. Is it a valid SOAP message as per the SOAP standard? Yes. The SOAP envelope and body tags seem valid.
2. Is it a valid XML format? Yes, it's a well formed XML file.
3. Are those elements without a namespace prefix valid? Yes. Elements can be in a default namespace or in no namespace at all.
4. Is the actual content of the body a valid messages? You can only tell if you verify the message you posted against the expected message as defined in the WSDL file of the web service.

All the elements in the body of the SOAP message should belong to specific namespaces, but sometimes a developer forgets to add a namespace annotation on the element, or copy-pastes something from some place else, or whatever, and you end up with weird looking XMLs like that. The service works and the message is correctly parsed, but it just looks funny.